# Retrieve data from a specific row entered by inputbox

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have a button and once clicked you are required to enter the customersID and once entered the data from that whole row should then load into the text box's, checkbox etc but when i do it, it prompts me with my own error i created saying Customer not found because it cant locate the ID of some sort? Any help appreciated!

In my opinion - When it loads * (All) from where ID is i am thinking it is only loading in all that data from that specific row at that Customer ID (in which i want) so i could use rows.items etc to load in my required information? Is this correct or? In general i just need help retrieving the data and putting it into my text boxes and such.

Code:

```vb
Private Sub Client(ByVal ans As String)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

    cmd = New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM tbl WHERE ID = ?"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ans
    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Does not exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Enter new ID!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Now loaded.", "Search Complete!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        'create data adapters
        sql = "Select * from tbl"
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl")
        RecCnt = ds.Tables("tbl").Rows.Count   'how many records in ds
        'assign data to lables

        TxtCI.Text = ds.Tables("tbl").Rows(0).Item(0)

        con.Close()
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Caller (Search button):
                    Client(custid)

Comment: is the CustomerID really a text field?  And please stop putting language tags ("VB.NET") in the title

Comment: In the database the data type is auto number but i am trying to use a text box so when i type 10 in and it exists it will load the data in row 10:)

Comment: Yes, but `cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ans` is passing it as text/string to the DB,.  You should turn on Option Strict, there are some implicit conversions in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery cannot work correctly with a SELECT statement. The returned value is the number of the rows affected but a SELECT statement doesn't change, insert or delete any row, so it is always zero.

You should use ExecuteReader (and this removes also the need to use an OleDbDataAdapter, a DataTable/Dataset and the long winded statement lines to retrieve values from the DataSet/Tables/Rows/Columns hierarchy

```
If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM tblcustomer WHERE CustomerID = ?"
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ans
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
if reader.Read() Then
    TxtCI.Text = reader(0).ToString()
    TxtName.Text = reader(1).ToString()
    ... and so on ...
Else
   MsgBox("Customer Does not exist!", ....)
```

Notice that you could substitute the column index (0,1,2 etc...) with the column name ("CI", "Name" etc...). This is somewhat better because it doesn't depend on the order returned by the SELECT * query (Of course, if you change the columns names you have the same problem but, at least, you should know about the change)

Comment: Says OleDbDataReader reader is not declared. Is this a mistype on your behalf or? And thanks!

Comment: @irishwill2008 he had some C# syntax in there...check again

Comment: Thank you both!:) If only i had a mind like yous id be flying through this assignment haha. I do things then turns out they dont work then im stuck etc etc. Turned out i needed to make a section where an end user can search and locate a customer within 30 seconds so a simple search button and enter the id might solve this:D